# Why Jetty STDOUT and STDERR logs are coming on console

Tags: logging, jetty

I am trying following command to start jetty

`/usr/bin/java -Djetty.home=/opt/jetty -Djetty.base=/opt/awesome/server  -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar jetty.state=/opt/awesome/server/jetty.state /opt/jetty/etc/jetty-logging.xml`

This command gives me output at console as

`StartLog to /opt/jetty/logs/start.log`

My question is why the above logs are coming to console however I have a jetty-logging.xml as below

`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">


<!-- =============================================================== -->
<!-- Configure stderr and stdout to a Jetty rollover log file        -->
<!-- this configuration file should be used in combination with      -->
<!-- other configuration files.  e.g.                                -->
<!--    java -jar start.jar etc/jetty-logging.xml                    -->
<!-- =============================================================== -->
<Configure id="logging" class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log">

    <New id="ServerLog" class="java.io.PrintStream">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.util.RolloverFileOutputStream">
          <Arg><Property name="jetty.logs" default="./logs"/>/yyyy_mm_dd.stderrout.log</Arg>
          <Arg type="boolean">false</Arg>
          <Arg type="int">90</Arg>
          <Arg><Call class="java.util.TimeZone" name="getTimeZone"><Arg>GMT</Arg></Call></Arg>
          <Get id="ServerLogName" name="datedFilename"/>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </New>

    <Get name="rootLogger">
      <Call name="info"><Arg>Redirecting stderr/stdout to <Ref refid="ServerLogName"/></Arg></Call>
    </Get>
    <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setErr"><Arg><Ref refid="ServerLog"/></Arg></Call>
    <Call class="java.lang.System" name="setOut"><Arg><Ref refid="ServerLog"/></Arg></Call>

</Configure>
```

`

Also when I do kill -3 {JAVA PID} the thread dumps logs are redirected to console only.
I want to capture this logs in some log file without using redirect option like `> or >>`

Here is the output of 
`cd /opt/awesome/server/ && java -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar --list-config`

`

```
Java Environment:
-----------------
 java.home = /opt/jdk1.7.0_45/jre
 java.vm.vendor = Oracle Corporation
 java.vm.version = 24.45-b08
 java.vm.name = Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
 java.vm.info = mixed mode
 java.runtime.name = Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
 java.runtime.version = 1.7.0_45-b18
 java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
 user.dir = /opt/awesome/server
 user.language = en
 user.country = US

Jetty Environment:
-----------------
 jetty.version = 9.2.19.v20160908
 jetty.home = /opt/jetty
 jetty.base = /opt/awesome/server

Config Search Order:
--------------------
 <command-line>
 ${jetty.base} -> /opt/awesome/server
 ${jetty.home} -> /opt/jetty


JVM Arguments:
--------------
 (no jvm args specified)

System Properties:
------------------
 (no system properties specified)

Properties:
-----------
 demo.realm = etc/realm.properties
 http.timeout = 30000
 https.port = 8443
 https.timeout = 30000
 jaas.login.conf = etc/login.conf
 jetty.delayDispatchUntilContent = false
 jetty.dump.start = false
 jetty.dump.stop = false
 jetty.keymanager.password = OBF:1u2u1wml1z7s1z7a1wnl1u2g
 jetty.keystore = etc/keystore
 jetty.keystore.password = OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4
 jetty.output.buffer.size = 32768
 jetty.port = 8080
 jetty.request.header.size = 8192
 jetty.response.header.size = 8192
 jetty.secure.port = 8443
 jetty.send.date.header = false
 jetty.send.server.version = true
 jetty.truststore = etc/keystore
 jetty.truststore.password = OBF:1vny1zlo1x8e1vnw1vn61x8g1zlu1vn4
 jsp-impl = apache
 org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356 = false
 threads.max = 200
 threads.min = 10
 threads.timeout = 60000

Jetty Server Classpath:
-----------------------
Version Information on 44 entries in the classpath.
Note: order presented here is how they would appear on the classpath.
      changes to the --module=name command line options will be reflected here.
 0:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-client-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
 1:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-continuation-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
 2:      1.4.1.v201005082020 | ${jetty.base}/lib/ext/javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar
 3:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.base}/lib/ext/test-mock-resources-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
 4:                    1.0.7 | ${jetty.home}/lib/ext/logback-classic-1.0.7.jar
 5:                    1.0.7 | ${jetty.home}/lib/ext/logback-core-1.0.7.jar
 6:                    1.6.6 | ${jetty.home}/lib/ext/slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
 7:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jetty.apache-jsp-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
 8:   3.8.2.v20130121-145325 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jsp/org.eclipse.jetty.orbit.org.eclipse.jdt.core-3.8.2.v20130121.jar
 9:                   8.0.33 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jsp/org.mortbay.jasper.apache-el-8.0.33.jar
10:                      2.3 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jsp/org.mortbay.jasper.apache-jsp-8.0.33.jar
11:                    1.2.1 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-impl-1.2.1.jar
12:                    1.2.1 | ${jetty.home}/lib/apache-jstl/org.apache.taglibs.taglibs-standard-spec-1.2.1.jar
13:                    (dir) | ${jetty.base}/resources
14:                    3.1.0 | ${jetty.home}/lib/servlet-api-3.1.jar
15:                 3.1.0.M0 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-schemas-3.1.jar
16:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-http-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
17:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
18:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-xml-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
19:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-util-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
20:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-io-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
21:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-jaas-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
22:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-jndi-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
23:      1.4.1.v201005082020 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi/javax.mail.glassfish-1.4.1.v201005082020.jar
24:                      1.2 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jndi/javax.transaction-api-1.2.jar
25:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-rewrite-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
26:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-security-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
27:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-servlet-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
28:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-servlets-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
29:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-webapp-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
30:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-deploy-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
31:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-plus-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
32:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/jetty-annotations-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
33:                    5.0.1 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/asm-5.0.1.jar
34:                    5.0.1 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/asm-commons-5.0.1.jar
35:                      1.2 | ${jetty.home}/lib/annotations/javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
36:                      1.0 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/javax.websocket-api-1.0.jar
37:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/javax-websocket-client-impl-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
38:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/javax-websocket-server-impl-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
39:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-api-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
40:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-client-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
41:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-common-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
42:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-server-9.2.19.v20160908.jar
43:         9.2.19.v20160908 | ${jetty.home}/lib/websocket/websocket-servlet-9.2.19.v20160908.jar

Jetty Active XMLs:
------------------
 ${jetty.base}/etc/jetty-logging.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-http.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-jaas.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-rewrite.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-ssl.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-https.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-deploy.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-plus.xml
 ${jetty.home}/etc/jetty-annotations.xml
 ${jetty.base}/etc/demo-rewrite-rules.xml
 ${jetty.base}/etc/test-realm.xml

`
```

Comment: report back the following (in your question): `$ cd /opt/awesome/server && java -jar /opt/jetty/start.jar --list-config`

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I have updated the description.